# android - Change bar color manteining default theme

Tags: android, colors

I want to change the background color of the action bar for all the views of my app without changing other attributes of the theme or style.

Any way to do it by xml resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For lesser API level check the [**Android#manual**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

For API Level greater than or equal 11.

Check the Version of the App and change the color of the ActionBar for API Level >11.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
             // only for HoneyComb and newer versions
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

            // title;
            bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>APP</font>"));

            //Rgb for yellow.
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(255,215,0)));
        }
```

Comment: I´m looking to do it by xml. Thanks.

Comment: @user2655890 MY answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to work with the styles.xml file tough. Not just the color, you can even provide your own drawable to the background.

Use the below.

        @style/MyActionBar

```
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>    </style>

<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#f00</item> oR
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">#F00</item> oR
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for more styles.

Comment: Please add the color codes in the colors.xml and then refer it here. :)

Comment: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.

Comment: Please see above, I have added the snippet. And here's the developers page for styling the ActionBar  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that was for the support library. Use the below.

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
</style>
```